"Pursuit curve" in geometry nodes
Given a Bezier curve object and some starting point, I want to approximate a type of "pursuit curve", like here:
Wikipedia "Pursuit curve"
Call the curve we're pursuing the "target curve", parameterized as T(x). Specifically I want my pursuit curve P(x) to be constructed so that the distance from the pursuit curve to the target curve measured along tangent segments is always 1. I think this will require that T(x) is moving "away" from the starting point P(0) at the beginning, but that's fine.
I am a complete geometry nodes novice, so I'm not sure if this is even possible. Here is my general idea though: My starting point is a mesh consisting of a single vertex (or maybe it's better to start with a curve object of only a single point), this starting point is at distance 1 from the starting point of the target curve, and we choose some small "step size" h which we'll use to construct the pursuit curve.
The result will be a curve P(x) starting at my starting point P(0). To construct the first point P(h), take the point along the segment from P(0) to T(h) which has distance 1 from T(h).
Then iterate this to build out the whole curve P(x). I think this will give an approximation to what I want?
I don't know how to do the various constructions with geometry nodes, and I'm not even sure it's possible at all to do the kind of iteration that I want. Is this just something I'll need to do in python? (which would be fine)
Here is an example, starting with the black curve and the start point for the green curve (everything is parameterized left to right), I want to produce the green curve.


Can you draw some examples of input and desired output?

@user2744010 To answer one of your subquestion : yes, it's totally doable in geometry nodes.

Thanks- I added a basic picture.

Oh so the dashed red lines all have the same length?

Given a curve, this setup creates the pursuer following the rules.

A visualization of the tangents (the file at the end of the answer contains the visualizer to be placed after the pursuit nodes)

The main node setup

Start subdividing the original curve in steps of equal length
Create a pursuer mesh and set only its start point at first
Set the positions of the remaining pursuer points in a loop:

Next pursuer point is in the line that connects the next pursued point to the previous pursuer point (this gives the approximated tangent direction)




Start line

Resamples the original curve in steps of equal length for iteration
Defines a start point for the pursuer (which can be in a circle around the start original point)

... by sampling the index 0 from the original line, add a vector rotated towards the given start angle with the given pursuit distance


Returns the resampled original, the pursuer curve with the start point set, the number of remaining points (iterations) to set position


Pursuit position

Given:

The previous point of the pursuer
The pursued point
The pursuit distance


Calculates the direction from the pursued point to the previous pursuer
Sets the size of this direction vector to the pursuit distance size
Places the new puisuer point as an offset from the pursued.


File - Version depicted above

(Navigate in and out of the node groups - the dark green ones - with tab)
File - With tangent visualizer


This is amazing! Thanks very much-

Hmmm.. The tangent is supposed to be at a constant length, but here the curves intersect so that requirement is clearly not met, right?

@MarkusvonBroady, at the "point of pursuit", the tangent is aiming at the other curve from the specified distance. If after completion you create lines connecting the points in both curves by index, you will see the lines with roughly the specified distance (depends on the resolution). If you think of both curves as cars racing one after the other, it gets clearer. There is a "time" involved. As the pursuer moves, the pursued moves away. And the curves are the track left behind.

In short: the intersection doesn't mean much. When the pursuer car reaches the intersection, the pursued car is way ahead on its track.

I'm still a little bit confused, it would help if the image was showing some pairs of points to see that they are indeed at equal distances, but I see now that indeed you can have 2 curves with their pairs of points being at equal distances (distances along tangent or just distances, in both cases) and yet intersect, just because the pairs of points aren't necessarily the pairs of closest points.

@MarkusvonBroady, added a tangent visualizer
